# How to check whether I'm using the cloud console free trial?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have already activated my free trail by giving my card details ,In payment overview it shows my card details too. but still is shows to activate the free trial.

**[Free trial status: $300.00 credit and 84 days remaining. With a full account, you'll get unlimited access to all of Google Cloud[Free trial activation message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaUkm.png)  Platform.]**

I need to know whether the free trial is activated or not.

Comment: This question has little to do with software, you can consult the Google Cloud Support to ask the status of your billing account.

Comment: @Benjamin - We are in a grey area here. Is the cloud part of `software tools commonly used by programmers` as defined by [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? If yes, then is understanding the cost of these tools on-topic? Major companies such as Google, Microsoft, AWS, etc have partnered with and sponsored Stack Overflow for support questions. Trying to create a well-defined definition of a `software problem` has become more difficult with the advances in our field. The cloud and AI/ML are making that even more challenging.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Google Cloud Billing account attached to the project. If you have Free Trial credits, they will appear on the right-hand side under Credits. If you have more than one credit type, each one will be listed separately under the image like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check this is to create a WindowsSevrerBased Vm in compute engine if it's a free account (not activated to fully paid) it will throw an error before creating an account to upgrade because Google cloud has now removed this in the free trial because of free trial abuse issues in past.

Comment: Google did not remove Windows servers from Free Trial because of abuse. Microsoft requires license fees for Windows Server. Windows Servers are not included in Free Tier or Free Trial because of license fees paid to Microsoft. You are confusing the different types of accounts that Google offers: Free Tier, Free Trial, and Paid. Accounts can have a combination of those types. Therefore your test will fail to detect if Free Trial is activated for an account.

Comment: thanks for good calrificaiton :)